# Siamese Network Architecture Issues for Two Dimension arrays.(TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, keras, siamese-network

I am developing a Siamese Based Neural Network model, following are my two arrays that I would need to provide to the siamese networks, that is I have two pairs of input each of size 30, so one pair will come from the LEFT and the other pair will come from the right.

```
EXAMPLES=10000
FEATURES=30
LEFT=np.random.random((EXAMPLES,FEATURES))
RIGHT=np.random.random((EXAMPLES,FEATURES))
LABELS=[]
for i in range(EXAMPLES):
    LABELS.append(np.random.randint(0,2))
LABELS=np.asarray(LABELS)
```

Now I want to develop the siamese neural network model that will consist of two neural network and I will train it on this data as I told before

**SIAMESE_MODEL**

```
inputShape=Input(shape=(FEATURES,))
left_input = Input(FEATURES,)
right_input = Input(FEATURES,)
    
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.summary()
   
    
encoded_l = model(left_input)
encoded_r = model(right_input)
    
L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]))
L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])
    
prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)
    


siamese_net.compile(loss="mse",optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))
siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)
siamese_net.fit(x=[LEFT,RIGHT],y=LABELS,batch_size=64,epochs=100)
```

**ERROR**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-71752a24704a> in <module>
      1 inputShape=Input(shape=(FEATURES,))
----> 2 left_input = Input(FEATURES,)
      3 right_input = Input(FEATURES,)
      4 
      5 model = Sequential()

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)
    170                                    'dimension.')
    171     if shape is not None and not batch_shape:
--> 172         batch_shape = (None,) + tuple(shape)
    173     if not dtype:
    174         dtype = K.floatx()

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can somebody guide me what is the correct way of building Siamese Network for 2D Matrices, for Images there are resources available , but for this kind of problems , I did not find any useful resources?

Regards

**UPDATE**
Yes the first problem was the shape of input and I was not specifying it correctly so after doing, it works well

```
inputShape=Input(shape=(FEATURES,))
left_input = Input(shape=(FEATURES,)) 
right_input =Input(shape=(FEATURES,))
```

I am now getting following as a siamese model summary

```
siamese_net.summary()

Model: "model_6"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_23 (InputLayer)           (None, 30)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_24 (InputLayer)           (None, 30)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_11 (Sequential)      (None, 5)            885         input_23[0][0]                   
                                                                 input_24[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None, 5)            0           sequential_11[1][0]              
                                                                 sequential_11[2][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_35 (Dense)                (None, 1)            6           lambda_3[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 891
Trainable params: 891
Non-trainable params: 0
```

My Question is where the other layers like 20 and 10 are gone now, is there something wrong?

Comment: your left_input and right_input are not specifying the shape correctly, you should do it as Input(shape=(FEATURES,))

Comment: Also the input shape is not an Input layer, its just a tuple

Comment: Not sure I can help with the broader question, but from reading the docs for tf.keras.Input, you are getting that error because you are passing an integer, rather than the expected tuple. In fact, you provide the input correctly on the line above: `Input(shape=(FEATURES, ))`

Comment: I had issues with the input shape, please see the updated post as now there is some issue with the model summary.

Comment: There is no issue, the Sequential model is acting like a layer.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, thanks a lot snoopy, you won my heart really. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `Input((FEATURES,))` and not `Input(FEATURES,)`

Comment: I have done that, thanks a lot, please see my updated question now.

Comment: They are hidden in `sequential_11 (Sequential)`, you can still see them through `model.summary()`